# New gradle version doesnot have dependencies section in App level build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

New gradle version doesnot have dependencies section in App level build.gradle
I want to add the implementation of FB login package and also some other packages but there is
no dependencies section but its working fine. Its a flutter project. The gradle version i am using is 6.5.1

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw  GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "MY APP ID"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add dependencies section below flutter :

```
flutter {
    source '../..'
}
//here
dependencies {
    ...
}
```

and a [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#changes_6.0) to docs.

Comment: wait i can do that myself?

Comment: I thought there was a problem that it didn't add that on it's on.

Comment: if it solved the problem don't forget to accept the answer.